# could not broadcast input array from shape (7,3) into shape (32,3) in Deep learning Studio Deep cognition

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

i want train my custom image dataset with Deep learning Studio Deep cognition
i use cloud/server from here https://app.deepcognition.ai/app/

my custom dataset https://mir.cr/5BTDN2TL

my model use AutoML (make model automaticly)

the dataset is successfully uploaded and can be to use but when i try to train it i got error

could not broadcast input array from shape (7,3) into shape (32,3)

can anyone help me to find the solution and explanation ?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try on their help-forum